# Order by DESC not working for custom variable $how

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following functions , I need to update **$how** so it sort videos by **site_views DESC**
I tried a lot of times but same output is displaying or I get empty output.Thanks in advance.

```
function list_videos($how = 'added', $limit = '15') { // newest, top views, etc etc etc
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pm_videos ORDER BY $how DESC LIMIT $limit");
    $result = '';
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {

        $results .= "
                <div class=\"item\">
                <a href=\"" . makevideolink($row['uniq_id'], $row['artist'], $row['video_title']) . "\"><img src=\"" . show_thumb($row['uniq_id']) . "\" alt=\"" . $row['video_title'] . "\" class=\"imag\" width=\"107\" height=\"72\" /></a>
                <a href=\"" . makevideolink($row['uniq_id'], $row['artist'], $row['video_title']) . "\" class=\"song_name\">
                <span class=\"artist_name\">" . fewchars($row['artist'] . " - " . $row['video_title'], 30) . "</span>
                </a>
                <span class=\"item_views\">" . pm_number_format($row['site_views']) . " views</span>
                </div>";
    }
    return $results;
}
```

Here featured videos are called but displayed separately from the other code(loaded with the player)

```
function make_voth() {

    global $config;

    $video_id = '';

    $sql = "SELECT uniq_id 
            FROM pm_videos 
            WHERE featured = '1' 
            ORDER BY rand() 
            LIMIT 1";
    $result =  @mysql_query($sql);

    if (@mysql_num_rows($result) == 0)
    {
        $sql = "SELECT uniq_id 
                FROM pm_videos,
                ORDER BY rand() 
                LIMIT 1";

        $result = @mysql_query($sql);
        $row    = @mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
        $video_id = $row['uniq_id'];
        mysql_free_result($result);
    }
    else
    {
        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
        mysql_free_result($result);

        $video_id = $row['uniq_id'];
    }

    return $video_id;
}
function show_more_featured($mvotd = '', $limit = 3) {
    //  todo
}
function show_voth_title() {    
    //  @deprecated
}
```

Comment: So.... `function list_videos($how = 'site_views', $limit = '15')` ?

Comment: yes $how = 'added', $limit = '15'

Comment: No. read what I just put there. It is the solution.

Comment: @DigitalChris the `function` in your comment may be confusing the op.

Comment: Still randomly displaying output (videos)

Comment: @bansi How is that possible? It is just an update of the first line of his code...

Comment: call your function like `list_videos('site_views');`

Comment: @DigitalChris, sry I misread...

Comment: I see what you're saying @bansi. The code you provided, and what I updated will change the function's DEFAULT values. You didn't provide any other code or instance of where you call list_videos().

Comment: Your table pm_videos had column added? and what is format of this column?

Comment: yes it have and it's format is time (time since added)like 1382306556

Comment: You are storing the time stamp, and it is fine for sorting. just look @DigitalChris answer. that should solve your problem

Comment: am retrieving featured videos and want to SORT them after site_views DESC because they are displaying randomlly for now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You currently have a function that defaults to showing 15 rows sorted by `added`. You can change this one of two ways:

Change the function itself. This will make the DEFAULT value be `site_views`:

```
function list_videos($how = 'site_views', $limit = '15') { // newest, top views, etc etc etc
```

Now if you call `list_videos()`, you will get 15 results ordered by site views desc.

OR

You can just change how you call the function in a certain place:

```
list_videos('site_views', 25);
```

This would order by site_views and show up to 25.

```
list_videos('video_title', 25);
```

Another example, probably not good to sort by name DESC but you get the idea...

Comment: using 'site_views' returns same result videos are randomly ordered like i was using order by rand() !

Comment: Then you're going to have to show some more code where it's called because what you have here is pretty simple.  `SELECT * FROM pm_videos ORDER BY site_views DESC` directly into mysql if you want and see those results and compare.

Comment: i added another code ,but changing by rand to desc will always play only one videos in the player.

Comment: Yes, make_voth() returns one video at random. Now I have no idea what your question even is.

Comment: am using make_voth seperately ,but my question was problem to display "featured" videos  after "site_views" DESC ,even used SELECT * FROM pm_videos Where featured=1 ORDER BY site_views DESC this not working correctly and showing featured videos randomly

Comment: I am fairly sure this is because you are changing the wrong code. Find where the actual code is that is generating your random videos and you will have your answer. Nobody can answer this unless they can search your code base.

Comment: if this is true why changing this code makes the output disappears?

Comment: anyway to retrieve those videos i use : $featured= list_videos('featured');

Comment: And believe me there is no where you can find another definition for list_videos or $ featured

Comment: Yeah, that's your problem! `list_videos('featured')` is going to get you up to 15 videos, ordered by featured DESC... which you're right will look random since featured will always be 1.

Comment: change it to site_views: `$featured= list_videos('site_views');`

Comment: Which you'll note is what I said to do in my answer above ;).

Comment: but all videos will be sorted by site_views while we have featured videos, and the regular videos( we need to have the site_views applied to featured videos.

Comment: Then you need a new function. Accept this answer and submit a new question and I'll write it for you :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20870543/order-by-featured-desc-not-working-for-a-custom-variable       thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
$featured = list_featured_videos('SELECT * FROM pm_videos  WHERE featured="1" ORDER BY site_views DESC LIMIT 10');
```